# How To Stop Sending To A Channel Once Context Is Canceled

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I face an error while working with channel and context in golang.

So my idea is,
I want to run 3 functions with goroutines and pass a channel into that function. If one of that functions is already sending a value into that channel, I want to stop other goroutines from sending it to the channel and close the channel.

My current problem is after a channel value is received, the other functions tried to send the value to that channel again

here is my code

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var err string

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    errChan := make(chan string)

    go one(ctx, errChan, cancel)
    go two(ctx, errChan, cancel)
    go three(ctx, errChan, cancel)

    err = <-errChan
    fmt.Println("recevied:", err)
    close(errChan)
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}

func one(ctx context.Context, c chan<- string, done context.CancelFunc) {

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Println("a goutines already sending to channel, one is lose.")
                return
            case c <- "from one":
                done()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}
func two(ctx context.Context, c chan<- string, done context.CancelFunc) {
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Println("a goutines already sending to channel, two is lose.")
                return
            case c <- "from two":
                done()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}
func three(ctx context.Context, c chan<- string, done context.CancelFunc) {

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                log.Println("a goutines already sending to channel, three is lose.")
                return
            case c <- "from three":
                done()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

What should I change from my code so I could only send one (exactly one) time to the channel and stop the whole operation?

Comment: Note that you do not need to close the channel as long as its not used in a `for-range` loop. All you need is that *single* receive operation that you already have. If there aren't any other receive ops then it is guaranteed that only one send will go through. And the other goroutines will exit once the `case <-ctx.Done()` is selected. So this is fine: https://go.dev/play/p/V82nlyGazVv. Btw note that there's no need for the goroutines inside the functions, nor is there any need for the loops: https://go.dev/play/p/7BWUXv_AJjW

Comment: @mkopriva thankyou for taking a look at the code. I really appreciate it. Okkay I'll just remove the anonymous goroutines inside each function. Thankyou very much

Comment: Most of the time the receiver does not close the channel, it is up to the sender to close the channel. Also to improve your inter-thread synchronisation process, I would cancel the context from the receiver as soon as a message is received from the channel.